# Flutter: Connection to a socket serve unsuccessful

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I have to connect to a socket serve in my Flutter App. I tried used some plugins like ADHARA_SOCKET_IO, but unsuccessful.
My back is built on nodeJS.

I tried run the serve disponibilized by the author of the ADHARA pluggin, to test my app, because on my API its dont work... but even the example APP run.
that is the error:

I/flutter (16986): io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error

(when I run the Author's serve+app)

p.s: I did check the path: '127.0.0.1:7000' / 0.0.0.0:7000.

So, in my app, I did write a function to call the socket's initialization in a button.

below is the code function. this is the error when call the function:

E/Adhara:SocketIOPlugin(15905): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
I/flutter (15905): io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error

```
    connectarSocket() async {

      SocketIO socket = await SocketIOManager().createInstance(
      SocketOptions('http://127.0.0.1:7000')); 
      socket.onConnect((data) {
        print("connected...");
        print(data);
        socket.emit("message", ["Hello world!"]);
      });
      socket.on("news", (data) {
        //sample event
        print("news");
        print(data);
      });
      socket.connect();

    }
```

actually when I use the same code as the example app (author) I get this:
    **I/flutter (16986): io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error**

when I use the function, I get this:
     **E/Adhara:SocketIOPlugin(15905): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
I/flutter (15905): io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error**

here is the pluggin repo:
https://github.com/infitio/flutter_socket_io

Comment: I'm on Flutter 1.7++;

Comment: Have you tried changing the URI to http://10.0.2.2:7000?

Comment: hey, I am facing the same error....did u find a resolution for this?

Comment: Hi, yes I did. Here a example of what I got to work (https://github.com/allansrc/flutter-socket-example) then a tutorial in Portuguese I wrote. U could translate it. http://dartlang.com.br/2019/09/09/flutter-e-socket-io-mas-sem-dor-de-cabeca/

Comment: hey...many thanks for your response...I tried your code, but I got below error:

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 10.0.0.2:80, null, null)

when, I changed, the URL to 'http://10.0.2.2:3000', I am still receiving the same error:

io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: websocket error

any idea, what is causing this issue?

Comment: Your uri syntax looks like incorrect. Use "http://" prefix on your string. e.g.: ```SocketOptions('http://10.0.2.2:300', ...```

Comment: If your Android sdk is on 28(device/emulator), it may cause issues like that. But I will test my code, it works months ago. Let us know if you solve it, please.

Answer (score -1):

So, after some spent time, I got solution.
I wrote a guide in Portuguese (my native language) that could be translate easily. Following the first link below there's it. The second one is the source code example for working.

http://dartlang.com.br/2019/09/09/flutter-e-socket-io-mas-sem-dor-de-cabeca/

https://github.com/allansrc/flutter-socket-example

Comment: HI and welcome to SO. Answers providing links only are discouraged, consider elaborating on the solution and if possible provide a code snippet in the response.

Comment: I'm "super busy" by now. I will make a detailed guide soon.